# Add column to a specific CSV row using Python pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to merge rows in csv files by matching the id with a given dictionary.

I have a dictionary: 
l= {2.80215: [376570], 0.79577: [378053], 22667183: [269499]}

I have a csv file.

```
          A        B        C        D      
2000-01-03 -0.59885 -0.18141 -0.68828 -0.77572
2000-01-04  0.83935  0.15993  0.95911 -1.12959
2000-01-05  2.80215 -0.10858 -1.62114 -0.20170
2000-01-06  0.71670 -0.26707  1.36029  1.74254
2000-01-07 -0.45749  0.22750  0.46291 -0.58431
2000-01-10 -0.78702  0.44006 -0.36881 -0.13884
2000-01-11  0.79577 -0.09198  0.14119  0.02668
2000-01-12 -0.32297  0.62332  1.93595  0.78024
2000-01-13  1.74683 -1.57738 -0.02134  0.11596
```

The output should be :

```
     A        B        C        D          E      F     
2000-01-03 -0.59885 -0.18141 -0.68828 -0.77572    0
2000-01-04  0.83935  0.15993  0.95911 -1.12959    0
2000-01-05  2.80215 -0.10858 -1.62114 -0.20170    376570 
2000-01-06  0.71670 -0.26707  1.36029  1.74254    0
2000-01-07 -0.45749  0.22750  0.46291 -0.58431    0
2000-01-10 -0.78702  0.44006 -0.36881 -0.13884    0
2000-01-11  0.79577 -0.09198  0.14119  0.02668    378053
2000-01-12 -0.32297  0.62332  1.93595  0.78024    0
2000-01-13  1.74683 -1.57738 -0.02134  0.11596    0
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
import pandas
data = panda.read_csv("thisfiel.csv")

data["F"] = data["B"].apply(lambda x: l[x])
```

But I couldn't get the aimed results.

Comment: I think Andy's answer is the right approach, however you shoudn't create a dict storing it's values as lists unless you happen to have more than 1 value for the entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
def getVal(x):
    try:
        return l[x][0]

    except KeyError:
        return 0

data['F'] = data['B'].map(getVal)
```

Comment: It didn't work ! I still get zeros in the new column

Comment: @user3378649 did you want zeros or NaN? You can change the `get(x,0)` to `get(x,NaN)`

Comment: Wired ! I am getting value "1" in all the new column

Comment: Literally, I should match: B.value, if (B.Value == l.item() ),  I should insert the item from dict in the same row where we found the value in column B.

Comment: This is what my code does not sure what your problem is, it works for me

Comment: I think the issue is that l is a dict with list values.

Comment: @AndyHayden well spotted, yes that would cause a problem, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you l were a DataFrame you could do a [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
In [11]: l_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(l, orient='index')

In [12]: l_df.columns = ['F']

In [13]: l_df
Out[13]: 
                     F
2.80215         376570
0.79577         378053
22667183.00000  269499
```

Merge on column A and the index of `l_df`:

```
In [14]: merged = df.merge(l_df, left_on='A', right_index=True, how='left')

In [15]: merged
Out[15]: 
                  A        B        C        D       F
2000-01-03 -0.59885 -0.18141 -0.68828 -0.77572     NaN
2000-01-04  0.83935  0.15993  0.95911 -1.12959     NaN
2000-01-05  2.80215 -0.10858 -1.62114 -0.20170  376570
2000-01-06  0.71670 -0.26707  1.36029  1.74254     NaN
2000-01-07 -0.45749  0.22750  0.46291 -0.58431     NaN
2000-01-10 -0.78702  0.44006 -0.36881 -0.13884     NaN
2000-01-11  0.79577 -0.09198  0.14119  0.02668  378053
2000-01-12 -0.32297  0.62332  1.93595  0.78024     NaN
2000-01-13  1.74683 -1.57738 -0.02134  0.11596     NaN
```

Note: atm NaN mean missing, you can fill them in with [fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
In [16]: merged['F'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: What If I need to match with A column, how can I merge it ?

Comment: @user3378649 I don't follow.. this is matching column A with the index of `l_df`

Comment: What Is l1, is it l_df

Comment: @user3378649 ah yes, my bad. Tried for better naming convention but missed one.